# default value using ng-select loop through array of object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For now the select is blank, I think angular added it by default. I want the default to be American, but I trid `ng-selected="country.name == 'American'"` it doesn't work?

my DOM

```
<select name="country" ng-model="user.country"
                  ng-options="country.name for country in country_list" >
              {{name}}
          </select>
```

http://jsbin.com/tocojojora/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Have you tried `ng-init`?

Comment: @Rajesh `ng-init="user.country='Singapore'"` doesn't work

Comment: In your case, you cannot assign a `string`,  you have to assign `user.country` one of the objects you  passed into `ng-options` like `ng-init = "user.country = country_list[0]"` etc.. then `ng-model` will automatically detect the default option.

Comment: @MariaJane I have added an answer with a working fiddle. Just a note, for sample, I have used `Angular 1.2.1` but should work for you. Also, next time if you provide a link to `Fiddle/JSBin...` please make sure it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, `ng-init="value='American Samoa'"` this will set the default value in dropdown

```
 <select ng-model="value" ng-init="value='American Samoa'"   ng-options="code.name as code.name for code in country_list">
 </select>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/zQDPoY4nRWLIgXo11b3x?p=preview)**

Comment: if my model is something.value it will not work. like `ng-init="user.country='Singapore'"` it won't work? why?

Comment: you should set in the ng-model , something like this,  <select ng-model="user" ng-init="user='American Samoa'"   ng-options="code.name as code.name for code in country_list">
       </select>

Comment: @MariaJane what do you actually want?

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.user = {country: $scope.country_list[4]};
```

Set the default user country in your controller(less logic in your html template).

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/retiwozifo/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code was not working was because of this:

```
ng-options="country.name for country in country_list"
```

In my understanding, here value will be `{name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'}` and not `Afghanistan` or `AF`.

You should try something like this:

```
ng-options="country.code as country.name for country in country_list"
```

Here value will `AF` and you can use `ng-init` to set it as

```
user.country = 'AS'
```

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/zfyxh468/).

Answer (score -1):

```
use something like this in your controller

$scope.user = {country:"American"}; //Default value to dropdown
```